# How to style `Sandpack`

Tags: css, reactjs, codesandbox

## Overview

I'm looking for the best practice when styling [`sandpack`](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/), I know there's the `@codesandbox/sandpack/unstyled` export, however this isn't a viable choice because they aren't modular enough to be interoperable with the regular styled exports. I don't mind styling from scratch, I would just prefer to not have to set syntax highlighting for the editor.

### What I want

```tsx
import {
  SandpackProvider,
  SandpackLayout,
  SandpackPreview,
  SandpackStack,
} from '@codesandbox/sandpack-react/unstyled'
import { SandpackCodeEditor} from '@codesandbox/sandpack-react'
import { sandpackTheme } from '../code-theme'

export function Component() {

  return (
    <SandpackProvider
      template="react-ts"
      theme={sandpackTheme}
    >
      <SandpackLayout >
        <SandpackStack>
          <SandpackPreview />
          <SandpackCodeEditor
            showInlineErrors
            showTabs
            showRunButton
            wrapContent
          />
        </SandpackStack>
      </SandpackLayout>
    </SandpackProvider>
  )
}
```

This way I could still use theme and have syntax highlighting alongside benefitting from the editor props such as `wrapContent` etc but I could apply my own classes to everything else. However this throws the error below.

```
Error: [sandpack-react]: "useSandpack" must be wrapped by a "SandpackProvider"
```

Which leads me to believe the styled and unstyled exports use two different `SandpackProvider` components leading them to be are incompatible.

### What I'm currently trying

To overwrite the default `sp-` [classes](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/docs/getting-started/layout#styling) from sandpack with my own custom css class.

```tsx
import {
  SandpackProvider,
  SandpackLayout,
  SandpackCodeEditor,
  SandpackPreview,
  SandpackStack,
} from '@codesandbox/sandpack-react'
import { sandpackTheme } from '../code-theme'


export function Component() {
  return (
    <SandpackProvider
      theme={sandpackTheme}
      options={{ classes: { 'sp-layout': 'ss-block' } }}
    >
      <SandpackLayout>
        <SandpackStack>
          <SandpackPreview />
          <SandpackCodeEditor
            showInlineErrors
            showTabs
            showRunButton
            wrapContent
          />
        </SandpackStack>
      </SandpackLayout>
    </SandpackProvider>
  )
}
```

However the runtime styles used by the library are overwriting the classes I pass in with the options object.

[image: Image of my css rule being overwritten]
[image: layout]

You can see my css rule `ss-block` is being overwrriten by `sp-c-iKJbEZ`

#### May or may not be helpful

[Josh Comeau](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/next-level-playground/) has a styled sandpack that's pretty close to what I'm looking for.
The [new React docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev) also implement a custom sandpack config however they do the syntax highlighting manually + are using an older verison